# persist mtu settings on boot2docker / docker-machine

Tags: networking, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

I have a host-system with several virtualbox boot2docker-vms installed via `docker-machine`. When I'm in a wireless network, the mtu-size is not low enough, resulting in an error when [pulling images](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15949) or doing other basic commands within the vms. In order to fix it, I have to set the mtu to a lower setting than the default.

However, since the boot2docker-images are reset after each reboot, the mtu is reset as well and I did not have found a way beside some hackish scripts to update it via sshing into every vm and changing it every time.

How can I persist the mtu changes to the vms? I'd rather not rebuild the boot2docker-images, which would force me to rebuild them after each upgrade.

Comment: Mind sharing the command line to set MTU?